# jq: convert array to object indexed by filename?

Tags: json, jq, pathname

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) how can I convert an array into object indexed by filename, or read multiple files into one object indexed by their filename?

e.g.

```
jq -s 'map(select(.roles[]? | contains ("mysql")))' -C dir/file1.json dir/file2.json
```

This gives me the data I want, but I need to know which file they came from.

So instead of

```
[
    { "roles": ["mysql"] },
    { "roles": ["mysql", "php"] }
]
```

for output, I want:

```
{
    "file1": { "roles": ["mysql"] },
    "file2": { "roles": ["mysql", "php"] }
}
```

I do want the ".json" file extension stripped too *if possible*, and just the basename (dir excluded).

---

#### Example

file1.json

```
{ "roles": ["mysql"] }
```

file2.json

```
{ "roles": ["mysql", "php"] }
```

file3.json

```
{ }
```

My real files obviously have other stuff in them too, but that should be enough for this example. file3 is simply to demonstrate "roles" is sometimes missing.

In other words: I'm trying to find files that contain "mysql" in their list of "roles". I need the filename and contents combined into one JSON object.

---

To simplify the problem further:

```
jq 'input_filename' f1 f2
```

Gives me all the filenames like I want, but I don't know how to combine them into one object or array.

Whereas,

```
jq -s 'map(input_filename)' f1 f2
```

Gives me *the same* filename repeated once for each file. e.g. `[ "f1", "f1" ]` instead of `[ "f1", "f2" ]`

Comment: post a minimal and testable input json content (from your input files)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added. Has to be in separate files I think, can't read from stdio because this question pertains to filenames.

Comment: I may have found a solution. I can just run JQ twice: `jq 'input_filename' $^ | jq -s`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your jq has `inputs` (as does jq 1.5) then the task can be accomplished with just one invocation of jq.
Also, it might be more efficient to use `any` than iterating over all the elements of `.roles`.

The trick is to invoke jq with the -n option, e.g.

```
jq -n '
  [inputs
   | select(.roles and any(.roles[]; contains("mysql")))
   | {(input_filename | gsub(".*/|\\.json$";"")): .}]
  | add' file*.json
```

Comment: If I understand this right, `any(.roles[]; contains("mysql"))` actually means "if any role contains *the substring* 'mysql'" no? For exact equivalence isn't `any(.roles[]; . == "mysql")` more appropriate?

Comment: I only used "contains" because that is what was in the original question, and it gives equivalence thereto.  However, if you require string equality, then of course you would use `==`.

Comment: Ah...fair enough. My mistake then :-) I thought it was like an "array contains" when I first found it :D

Answer (score 2):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq 'if (.roles[] | contains("mysql")) then {(input_filename | gsub(".*/|\\.json$";"")): .}
    else empty end' ./file1.json ./file2.json | jq -s 'add'
```

The expected output:

```
{
  "file1": {
    "roles": [
      "mysql"
    ]
  },
  "file2": {
    "roles": [
      "mysql",
      "php"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Didn't know about `if`. Can also be done with `select`: `jq 'select (.roles[]? | contains("mysql")) | {(input_filename | gsub(".*/|\\.json$$";"")): .}' $^ | jq -s 'add'` (formatted for Make)