# Merging JSON files under their own key using jq

Tags: json, bash, file, merge, jq

Trying to merge an undefined number of JSON files into one, each represented in their own key (using `jq`).

Example:

```
$ cat foo.json
{
  "test1":"Foo"
}
$ cat bar.json
{
  "test2":"Bar"
}
$ jq -s "{`ls | sed -r 's/\.json$/: \./' | tr '\n' ', ' | sed 's/.$//'`}" `ls`
{
  "foo": [
    {
      "test1": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "test2": "Bar"
    }
  ],
  "bar": [
    {
      "test1": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "test2": "Bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I am trying to output:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "test1": "Foo"
  },
  "bar": {
    "test2": "Bar"
  }
}
```

For example: `foo` being the name of the first file and expected to be the key for its content in the final output.

(Also, I feel like this is not really pretty to call `ls` twice for the same thing, but not sure if there is a way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly based on [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219620/5291015) use inputs with `-n` to read the JSON contents in one shot and removing the extension from the filename

```
jq -n '
  [inputs
   | {(input_filename | gsub(".*/|\\.json$";"")): .}]
   | add' *.json
```

Also as suggested by the original author, the solution above only removes UNIX-style paths, but not Windows-style paths.